# Область видимости для template шаблона и классов

Tags: c++

Всем привет, мне нужна исправить и разделить код на 2-две части. Хочу сделать все по правилам хорошего кода.

Вот код

```
using namespace std;
class A
{   
    public:
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
        A(T1 y, T2 d, T1 t, T2 f, T3 w, T4 l, T5 h, T2 r, T3 z, T4 n) {

          ifstream in;
          open_in<T3, T5>(in, y, d);

        // тут начинается другой код который дальше работает с переменными
        // например простой цикл который должен получить данные y и продолжить
        // свое выполнения подсчетов, но к сожалению он получает старые данные
        // которые были добавлены в main
        // A("955635332", "2.bin", "3.bin", 666, 555, 111, 24, 333, 777, 10);

          ofstream out;
          open_out<T1,T2>(out, y,  d);

        }
    private :
       // первый сохраняет файл
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void open_out(ofstream & out,T1 a, T2 b) {
                  out.open(b, ofstream::app);
                  out.write((char*)& a, sizeof(a));
                  out.close();
        }

        // второй читаем данные файл
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void open_in(ifstream & in,T1 a, T2 b) {
                  in.open(b, ios::binary);
                  in.read((char*)& a, sizeof(a)))
                  in.close();
        }

    };
}

void main()
{
    A("955635332", "2.bin", "3.bin", 666, 555, 111, 24, 333, 777, 10);

    return;
}
```

В разделе `private` у меня две разных функции один сохраняет другой читает файл.
В основном мне нужно поместить их в другой общий класс.
И самое главное мне нужно что бы эти функции передавали данные на класс `A`
Сейчас когда `ifstream` который читает данные с файла завершает свое исполнения ничего не передает в переменную `y`, хотелось бы что бы после прочтения данных при вызове `open_in<T3, T5>(in, y, d);` переменная в шаблоне `T1 y` стала использовать полученные данные с `T1 a`

Если вы знаете как сделать еще удобней и кручи можете поделится

Comment: не в обиду, но этот код выкиньте на свалку

Comment: @ARHovsepyan :) лучше не видел чем этот, самый читаемый код с использованием ооп
Вам ненарвиться потому что он плохопанимаемый для вас?
или сам код плохо будет работать.

Comment: Нет, для меня неплохопонимаемый, какраз я хорошо понимаю, что класс должен выражать некую логичную сущность, а не легко читаемую ерунду, поэтому я хорошо понимаю, что нужно выкинуть этот код на свалку.  Придет время, вы сами это поймете(если не сейчас), но пока я просто дал совет, а обьяснять причины слышком долго будет, тем более, что вы не стараетесь самим что нибудь сделать и не можете замечать случайно допущенную мною лишнюю скобку, а просите меня убрать все ошибки, чтобы код компилировался. Это значит, что вы ожидаете готовые коды, потому я прошлый раз не исправил ошибку, а удалил ответ

Comment: Я бы сам исправил просто не дошел до вашего кода. зря удалили я его конечно сохранил :)

Comment: в своих функциях хотябы осуществите проверку на открытие файла. Если файл все же не открылся(причины могут быть разные), то  весь  ваш код и дальнейшее его использование, становится  пузырьком  воздуха

Comment: У меня код тоже с проверкой, я через цикл реализовал, то что вы видите это простенький пример, для меня не так важен код как метод разделения и взаимодействие между классами и шаблонами template
пока я не могу понять как сделать область видимости в этом проблема.

Comment: хотите может в телеграмм пообщаться я скину код целый посмотрите, а то этот сайт не дает переписываться в личных сообщениях

Comment: вот вы пишете, например:   out.open(b, ofstream::app);  Т.е. вы вызываете метод класса  ofstream для обьекта  out,   этот метод в своем первом аргументе ожидает обьект типа(только) const char* , а вы взяли тип для .  b  сделали шаблонным, и при любом инстанцировании шаблона, кроме как  с  const char*, вы получите ошибку. Где смысль  для шаблона?  Этот шаблон не то что бессмыссленный, но и вредный. И  этот код с начала и до конца   подобным образом не имеет ничего общего с логически оссмыссленным понятием

Comment: Я могу в шаблоне создать переменную типа const char и тогда нельзя будет указывать кроме char ничего другого, главный смысл что бы не лазить в код а изменять только функцию вызова, все остальное будет в переменных.

Comment: т.е. вы не станете определять шаблон, а определите только одну специализацию. Можно, но тогда сделать шаблонным тип, который может быть только конкретным каким то, это означает идти в гипермаркет и сказать "покажите мне все виды вашего товара, но я буду покупать только хлеб". Что подумают о вас?...

Comment: Например мне же ничего не мешает делать так
`int go = 214124;
char outF = "2bit.bit";
A(go, outF, "3.bin", 666, 555, 111, 24, 333, 777, 10);`

Comment: Я думаю можно пойти дальше и сделать спец цикл который сам будет назначать что нужно и заполнять пустые пространства по умолчанию

Comment: Шаблоны не предназначены, чтобы пихать их везде. Что такое y? Зачем так много шаблонных параметров? Если не очень хорошо получается писать, то почитайте [эту книгу](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/11/27/cpp_templates_2ed_review.aspx). Но вам нужно уже понимать c++ на начальном уровне.

Comment: я немного понимаю видосов насмотрелся

Comment: `void open_out(ofstream & out, const T1& a, const  std::string& b);` и `void open_in(ifstream & in, T1& a, const std::string& b)` сразу бросается в глаза. Даже лучше static их сделать. Зачем имя файла вы сделали шаблоном непонятно. Параметры в эти функции стоит передавать по ссылке. P.s. Так и не понял, что вы хотите сделать. Вы сами поняли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку: на наличие ошибок не проверено, но, как я понел, для вас главное идея...

```
template <typename T>
class A {
protected:
    fstream file;
public:
    A(const char* name, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::app)
    {
        file.open(name, mode);

        //проверка на открытие
    }
    ~A() 
    {
        if (file.is_open())  file.close();
    }
    A& new_file(const char* name, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::app)
    {
        if (file.is_open())  file.close();
        A<T> a(name, mode);
        file = a.file;
        return *this;
    }
    fstream& write(const T& obj)
    {
        //ваш код
        if (file.is_open()) {
            file << obj;
            file.close();
        }
        //...
        return file;
    }   
    fstream& read(T& obj)
    {
        //...
        return file;
    }

    //...
};
```

Не знаю что вам нужно, но вот пример взоимодействия
(любой из функций можете определить в `В`,
 можете сделать этии функции виртуальными
 и в `В` переопределить. Только вы сами знаете что вам нужно):

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A {            
public:
    B(const char* name, std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::app)
        : A<T>(name, mode) {}
    //перегрузка для последовательностей и контейнеров
    template <class Cont>
    fstream& write(const Cont& conteiner)
    {
        //ваш код
        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (auto obj : conteiner)
                file << obj;
            file.close();
        }
        //...
        return file;
    }
};
```

Что вы вернете из функций, тоже решать вам, в соответствии с желаемым результатом. И наконец, существует заголовочный файл  `<filesystem>`,    и вы можете использовать возможности(классы и функции), предоставленные там, можете изучать как  принимаются решения при их определении, можете читать учебники и статьи, и т.д. и т.п. Старайтесь здесь задавать конкретные вопросы, а не такие, чтобы никто не мог помочь вам без долгих пояснений и написании  кодов за вас

Comment: Да ваше решения тоже будет работать но она немного сложней, конечно в будущем это может понадобится для меня.
Я смотрел много видеороликов правила хорошего кода и там четко было написано, если вы делаете код очень сложный в конечном итоге продуктивность будет падать в итоге придется переписывать код вместо внесения изменений.
Поэтому я стараюсь делать как можно проще что бы вносить изменения.
Так же я свой код вынес в другой класс и сделал наследования.

Comment: совсем наоборот, мой пример проще, чем тот, котрый вы предостаили, поскольку  у меня один аргумент шаблона для чтения и записи разных типов, а в предосталенном вашем примере все запутано. И я ничего искусственно не усложнял: есть класс, есть его методы, которые должны проверять состояние файлового потока. Иначе никак... По вашей логике, все стандартные классы не имеют право на существование, поскольку там намного сложнее. Когда читаете что то, нужно правильно понимать. Речь наверняка ведется о лишных сложностях и  об искусственном разбухании кода...

Comment: А что значит проверять, зачем так усложнять метод проверки записи в файл?
Я сделал вот так
`do
   input_file.open(b, ios::binary);
if (!input_file.is_open()){
код
}else{
код
}
while (!input_file.is_open());
input_file.close();`

Comment: Получается проверку осуществляет цикл, если файл вдруг не открылся он будет бесконечно пытаться открыть его пока не откроет. при этом может писать что файл не открыт или не может быть открытым, так же можно вывести причину почему файл не открыт.
Единственно что мне нужно добавить это проверку на запись внутри файл, но тоже вопрос нужно ли эта проверка

Comment: Что касается проверки на запись меня заинтересовал этот метод

`output_file.exceptions(ofstream::badbit | ofstream::failbit | ofstream::eofbit);`

Но я пока не понимаю как он работает и нужно ли вызывать его в цикле если есть ошибка

Comment: Это означает, что при любом неправильном вводе  будет генерировано исключение  std::ios_base::filure, но это лишнее, поскольку по умолчанию  эти биты установлены

Answer (score -1):

Друзья решения оказалось простым надо было в шаблон template добавить ссылку **&** а не переменную.
вот так

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    void open_out(ofstream& output_file, T1& a, T2& b)
```